Windows 11 (ASUS B550M WiFi) - is my Realtek NIC causing these problems?
My PC has been experiencing intermittent disconnects from the internet (whether on WiFi, Ethernet or even tethering on 5G). Other devices have some issues, but none as frequent as my PC.
Motherboard was replaced last week (with the same board that has a Realtek NIX) - and it fixed absolutely nothing (I’ve run a cable, switched providers etc)

"Other devices have some issues" suggests to me that it isn't the PC being the problem. How do you know that the disconnect has happened - for example, does the PC say it has lost the connection? Has anything remained the same through the provider change, for example a modem, or a mains extension lead, or a wall socket?

Why was the motherboard replaced?  I hope it wasn't due to the disconnect issue, as it is clear, the problem was NOT caused by the adapter on the original motherboard.

It was replaced (fortunately under warranty) by the useless company  I bought the PC from. I’ve considered getting a router to see if that fixes any of the WiFi issues but the issues with the PC persist whether I use its cable, WiFi(which i was using  on my previous provider or tethering my phone. That’s why I suspected the Realtek NIC (which of course my GPU is too thick and I can’t do anything myself, hence why I contacted the company for help). They’re more of ‘professionals’ so if anyone’s to blame it’s them.

@RachaelTraverso The Realtek NIC is used for the wired Ethernet, but not the Wi-Fi.

Sorry - this is the Ethernet that I use but it doesn’t matter if the PC uses WiFi, Eth from my router or tethering my 5G to try and rule out a connection   Fault. I’m getting a new cable and running it up the stairs to rule that out

Looking like the Ethernet cable is not the fault

@RachaelTraverso Does the internet reconnect on its own? If so, how long does it seem to take to reconnect? Is it long enough to check the lights on the modem?

The other thing you could try is making a complete backup of your computer and then reinstalling Windows: Microsoft: Give your PC a Fresh Start. If you are not totally confident that your backup works, then you may want to find more articles describing how to reinstall Windows.
